# HTTP Post response error - "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."

Tags: marketing-cloud, httppost, marketingcloudapi

I am trying to retrieve a portion of the response related to a template-based email via a Cloudpage. I am attempting to get the "items" portion of the response. I get the following error:

```
Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

This the section of the overall code that handles the request:

```
    function retrieveEmailTemplate(accessToken, emailTemplateName, tenantURL)
    {
       var url = 'https://'+ tenantURL +'.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/query';

       var contentType = 'application/json';

       var headername = ["Authorization"];

       var headervalue = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

       var payload ='{"query":{"leftOperand":{"property":"name","simpleOperator":"equal","value":"'+ emailTemplateName +'"},"logicalOperator":"AND","rightOperand":{"property":"assetType.name","simpleOperator":"equal","value":"templatebasedemail"}},"fields":["views","data","content"]}';

      try {
        var emailRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headername, headervalue);

        var emailResult = Platform.Response.Write(emailRequest.Response[0]["items"]);

        return emailResult;

      }
      catch(err) {
        Platform.Response.Write("This is an error: " + err);
      }
    }
```

This is part of the response I will normally get if I remove the `["items"]` part of the `emailResult` variable:

```
    {
        "count": 1,
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 50,
        "links": {},
        "items": [
            {
                "id": {{REMOVED}},
                "customerKey": "{{REMOVED}}",
                "objectID": "{{REMOVED}}",
                "contentType": "application/vnd.etmc.email.Message; kind=template",
                "assetType": {
                    "id": 207,
                    "name": "templatebasedemail",
                    "displayName": "Template-Based Email"
                },
                "name": "{{REMOVED}}",
                "description": "",
                "owner": {
                    "id": {{REMOVED}},
                    "email": "{{REMOVED}}",
                    "name": "{{REMOVED}}",
                    "userId": "{{REMOVED}}"
                }, ....
```

Are there any adjustments that need to be made to prevent the error and retrieve the "items" section of the response? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to parse the response before calling out items.

```
Platform.Function.ParseJSON(emailRequest.Response[0]).items
```